# SAP Business Object addon

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to implement my own addon and include it within my sap business object reposts Or i have to arrange this with the sap team so that they enbale me to do something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be registered as a SAP partner in order to register your addOn in SAP(This is also needed to get the necessary library files). Developing an addOn won't be that difficult if you are familiar with c# or VB. If you already have SAP B1 installed check the sample codes provided under the directory C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with the help of SDK library provided by SAP you can integrate.
There are some addons which are by default provided, if it is 3rd party need to approach
SAP/Partner company for further license.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with SAP team at first. Because add-on is not in support list generally. If you decide to develop any 3rd tool or use API to access data, you have to use SDK provided by SAP BO, check it from official site doc and go on.
https://help.sap.com/doc/7adfc93c56564bb0bade737ea8a3a61f/4.2.4/en-US/index.html